Under what circumstances does Invoke-WebRequest not return an object?
I'm using Powershell to pull down some appsettings.json files for applications that are hosted in Azure Functions. I'm looping through the functions and pulling down the appsettings to later perform some operations on. The code looks something like:
  # Where the appsettings json lives on the function/service
  $pathToFile = "/site/wwwroot/appsettings.json"

  # get scm site cred
  $publishProfile = az webapp deployment list-publishing-credentials --name $functionApp.Name -g $functionApp.ResourceGroupName | ConvertFrom-Json
  $credential = [PSCredential]::new("$($publishProfile.publishingUserName)", (ConvertTo-SecureString -AsPlainText $publishProfile.publishingPassword -Force))
  $api = "$($publishProfile.scmUri)/api/vfs"

  $jsonFileContent = Invoke-RestMethod -Credential $credential -Authentication Basic -Method Get -Uri "$api/$($pathToFile.Trim('/'))"


In the majority of cases, this is working well and $jsonFileContent contains a powershell object that I can work with easily later. For some of the functions though, I can't work out why the $jsonFileContent appears to contain a string containing the JSON.
> $jsonfileContent.gettype()

IsPublic IsSerial Name                                     BaseType
-------- -------- ----                                     --------
True     True     String                                   System.Object

If I write it out to a file with a .json extension and open it, everything appears to be valid in terms of the composition of the JSON.
I can use Convert-ToJSON and ConvertFrom-JSON to freely transform it between a regular string and a json formatted string but I am struggling to convert it into something that's easier to work with.
Any ideas what is going on here or what could be causing this?
Thanks

Compare a good and bad json string and see if the structure is different.

Normally, Invoke-RestMethod automatically parses a JSON response into a [pscustomobject] graph (i.e., in a manner of speaking, it has ConvertFrom-Json built in) and only falls back to outputting a string if the response isn't valid JSON (or isn't valid XML).
